# How to get the process names of applications in taskbar using c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get the list of process names for the applications which are in task bar.
How to get that? Is there any way to filter the criteria from process[] ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use MainWindowTitle

```
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (var item in processes)
            {
                if(item.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(item.MainWindowTitle);
            }
```

Comment: Looks like worth testing out.

Comment: window title length >0 doesn't mean it's visible and also doesn't mean it's application window

Comment: It doesn't work with unnamed windows (have an empty title).