# Configure 'BackgroundService' to run in the User Session

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've been working on a little Project, for which a windows service (with the 'new' WorkerService-Template) runs in the background keeping track of every Process that runs like this:

```
            while (//...)
            {
                 processes = Process.GetProcesses();

                foreach (var item in processes)
                {
                    //...
                }
                    //...
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
```

It works fine when I run it from Visual Studio, but when I register the service with `sc create ".T" binPath="..."` and try to run it with `sc start ".T"`(in cmd as an admin), it just sees an 'explorer' process. It only checks processe that meet this condition `item.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0 || (item.ProcessName.ToLowerInvariant() == "explorer")`, so basically all the processes [in the Taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366321/how-to-get-the-process-names-of-applications-in-taskbar-using-c) and the explorer Proccess, as the Length check doesn't seem apply to it. It's not that I registered the Service wrong or any of the Setup-Codein the Program-Class is bad, it's just that the `Process.GetProcesses()`-Call doesnt work with window services as I thought it would.

I verify all this by letting the service log everything(all Processes it captured) to a file with timestamps.

After some research it turns out, that services run in a '0 Session' and therefore cannot interact with processes in the User(1) Session.

I've tried changing the settings in the ['Log-On' properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/262ET.png) in the Windows-Service-App back and forth from 'Local System' to 'This Account' and I've also tried doing that with the `sc config ".T" obj= "..." password= "..."` (and it showed success, so the comand wasnt typed wrong or anything), but nothing resolved the issue of the Call not registering the wanted processes.

*What am I missing? How to resolve his issue?*

*And if it can't be configured to see processes in the user session, what would be alternatives?* (service like; so no ui but permission to write to a file and access the user-processes)

I've also tried the 'old' Windows-Service template, but there not even the registration of the service worked after long work, so I'd rather not use that. Besides that the [microsoft docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/262ET.png) say, that you should use the new template and BackgroundService-Class.

Comment: Do you need the check for MainWindowTitle? It should work without that check as Processes should be accessible but just not things depending on a desktop like Window Titles.

Comment: @Ralf Sorry for the late answer, but I only want to register processes that are shown in the taskbar and one post (also linked above) suggests that you should check for the length of the window title. Though i found that method unreliable and I am now using a different one, using several Windows-API calls. That btw resolved the problem, as I don't have to use Process.GetProcesses() anymore, but if you have an answer to the question, still feel free to post it here.